# How to Display Pop Up when the Polygon is clicked in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms, polygon

I'm using WEB API to retrieve coordinates and display them as polygons on my Map.
Now I want to make those Polygons when they clicked to display a pop with more information from the API.
My Xaml:

```
  <maps:Map x:Name="map">
            <x:Arguments>
                <maps:MapSpan>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <maps:Position>
                            <x:Arguments>
                                <x:Double>-30.241943</x:Double>
                                <x:Double>25.771944</x:Double>
                            </x:Arguments>
                        </maps:Position>
                        <x:Double>
                            20
                        </x:Double>
                        <x:Double>
                            20
                        </x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </maps:MapSpan>
            </x:Arguments>
            <maps:Map.MapElements>
            </maps:Map.MapElements>
        </maps:Map>
    </StackLayout>
```

then my C# code for adding Polygons:

```
foreach (var tempList in AlertsList)
{
    string alertType = tempList.AlertType;
    if (alertType == "Advisory")
    {
    polygon = new Polygon();
    polygon.StrokeColor = Color.FromHex("ffff00");
    polygon.FillColor = Color.FromHex("ffff00");
    polygon.StrokeWidth = 5f;

    foreach (var Poly in tempList.Polygon)
    {
        float Lat = float.Parse(Poly[0]);
        float Long = float.Parse(Poly[1]);
        polygon.Geopath.Add(new Position(Lat, Long));
    }
    // add to map
    map.MapElements.Add(polygon);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Gesture recognizer to your view and display the popup based on your requirement. You can add Gestures to any view in Xamarin Forms.

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap to display the popup here
};
[YourView].GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

If you want to display a simple alert dialog then you can use the [DisplayAlert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.displayalert) in Xamarin forms to achieve the result. Refer the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups) for more details.

If you wish to display customized popup based on your UI requirements, then there is an excellent open source plugin ([Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)) available for it. You can download the [NuGet here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rg.Plugins.Popup/). It has various examples as well for you to achieve what you want.

I hope that helps you.